# VB form to database (Data Saves Twice When Submitted)

Tags: vb.net

I wrote my vb.Net code that submits data from vb form to Microsoft SQL Server 2014 database. The problem I encountered was that data submitted saves Twice in the database even if primary and unique keys were set.
CHECK MY QUERY

```vb
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO VisitorsRegister VALUES('" & sn.Text &
    "','" & mn.Text & "','" & ln.Text & "','" & gender & "','" & comboDay.Text &
    "','" & date5.Text & "','" & pur.Text & "','" & ici.Text & "','" & ico.Text &
    "','" & ti.Text & "','" & tmo.Text & "','" & fn.Text & "','" & ra.Text &
    "','" & fu.Text & "')", conn)
Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dt As New DataTable
sda.Fill(dt)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("Data Successfully Inserted", vbInformation, "Success")
```

Comment: There's a lot to address here. First and foremost, please use your eyes to look at the preview of your question and don't submit it if it's a complete mess. If you can't be bothered to take the time to format your question to make it readable then you'll find people less inclined to take the time to help you, because they have to waste it working out what you're even saying in the first place. Not only was your code nor formatted as code, it didn't even contain line breaks. Simply copying and pasting would have done that but, even if you messed that up, you could still edit it by hand.

Comment: Secondly, you need to spend some time working through an ADO.NET tutorial because what you're doing there makes no sense. If you learned the basics from a tutorial and followed what it actually said, you'd never have made the mistake you did in the first place and you wouldn't need to ask this question because there'd be no issue.

Comment: Thirdly, as may or may not be covered by a tutorial - the goods ones would cover it - you should absolutely NOT be building your SQL code using all that string concatenation. It makes the code hard to read and thus error prone, it leads to formatting issues and, most importantly, it leaves you wide open to SQL injection attacks, which could corrupt or even delete your entire database. You should immediately learn how to use parameters. [Here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) is my take on the subject. Also, it's good practice to ALWAYS specify columns.

Comment: This is an INSERT command. It does not pull data from the database and hence there is nothing to be filled into your DataTable. You must make a subsequent SELECT command to fill the DataTable. Also use command parameters instead of string concatenation.

Comment: OT, you might want to think about using better, i.e. more descriptive, names for your controls and everything else in general as well. It's fine to, for instance, name a `DataTable` variable `dt` when it's only used for a few lines after its declaration because it's obvious what it is. You look to have a bunch of `TextBoxes` with virtually useless names though, so that is very likely to cause problems. Those names mean nothing to anyone else reading your code and, if you put that code down for a while and come back to it, I guarantee that they'll mean nothing to you either.

Comment: And, btw., I don't see anything being done twice here.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, there are two things being done once each, both of which will execute the command that inserts a record to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You should absolutely not be using a data adapter here. The fact that you are demonstrates that you don't know how to use one so you need to go back to the drawing board and learn how to use ADO.NET properly. The point of a data adapter is to retrieve data from the database into a `DataTable` and save changes from that `DataTable` back to the database. You don't want to do either of those things so there's no reason to be using a data adapter at all.

It gets worse though. You create a command object containing an `INSERT` statement and then you assign that to the `SelectCommand` property of your data adapter. When you call `Fill`, the point is that the `SelectCommand` is executed and the specified `DataTable` is populated with the results of the query. A query contains a `SELECT` statement, not an `INSERT` statement. You don't want to populate a `DataTable` and you couldn't do so with an `INSERT` statement anyway, so why do you have a data adapter at all? Get rid of it.

The reason the data gets inserted twice is that you're executing your SQL code twice: once when you call `Fill` and once when you call `ExecuteNonQuery`. If you get rid of the worse-than-useless data adapter then you'll only be executing it once and the problem goes away.

Comment: It's unfortunate that I actually didn't post the whole code here but the reason for data adapter is that I have grid view on the same form. As well am still learning. I was told to research. Thank you for the advice 

Comment: @TumusiimeEdgar, if you want to use a data adapter then use a data adapter and get rid of the call to `ExecuteNonQuery`. The reason that your data is being saved twice is that you're saving it twice. Save it once, one way or the other. That said, you're using the data adapter all wrong there anyway, so there's no way that one could be displaying data in a grid. Maybe you have another one that does that but this one certainly doesn't. I suggest that you read [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872) to learn the basics of ADO.NET scenarios.